# In React typescript how to pass checkbox status from Sidebar component to MainContent component to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I am developing Dashboard using React Typescript.
Need help to pass checkbox selection values from Sidebar component to MainContent component, so that based on the checkbox selection I can filter the cards in MainContent page.
As shown in the below image.

1. I have sidebar component displaying filters with checkboxes.
2. In MainContent component I am rendering cards.
3. I would like to refresh the MainContent component based on the filters selection.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Header from 'components/Common/Header'
import Sidebar from 'components/Common/Sidebar'
import ErrorBoundary from 'components/Common/ErrorBoundary'

const MainContent = React.lazy(() => import('components/Tasks/MainContent'))

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
`

const Jobs = () => {
  return (
    <>
   
      <Wrapper>
        <Sidebar />
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
            <MainContent />
          </React.Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  )
}

export default Jobs
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Feel free to reach me on mjariwala98#4797 discord will solve this over the weekends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lift state of the filters up to your upper-level `Jobs` component and pass the state and state setters to the children components `Sidebar` and `MainConent`as appropriate. In your case I guess that `Sidebar` needs both the current filter state and the state setter function, while the `MainContent` only needs to know about the current state

Something like:

```jsx
const Jobs = () => {
  // Initialize filters state with a tuple of booleans
  const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState([false, false])

  return (
    <>
      <Wrapper>
        {/* Pass the filter state and the function to mutate filter state to the sidebar, for it to render the checkboxes */}
        <Sidebar filters={filters} setFilters={setFilters}/>
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <React.Suspense fallback={null}>
            {/* Pass the filter state and use it determine what do display */} 
            <MainContent filters={filters}/>
          </React.Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks @Gustav , I am just curious to know, in SideBar Component I am rendering CheckBoxes. Is it possible to refresh MainContent component from SideBar Component with the help of React.ChangeEvent.

Comment: A component will re-render whenever its props are changed.  So, yes - MainContent will refresh if its prop is mutated from an action i SideBar. (React.ChangeEvent has nothing to do with that though)

Comment: thank you @Gustav, lifting up status will solve my issue.

Comment: Glad it helped!